# How to compute the following definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-(ap - ibx)^2} dp$$
where $a$, $p$, $b$, $x$ are real numbers and $a$ is greater than zero.
I think that I should declare a new variable $m = ap - ibx$, then $dm = adp$ and the integral will just become:
$$\frac{1}{a}\int_{}^{} e^{-m^2} dm$$
However, it is not quite a Gaussian since $m$ is complex and the borders of integration will be something like $(-\infty - ibx)$ and $(+\infty - ibx)$. Therefore I do not know how to prove that the given integral should be equal to $\sqrt{\pi}/a$.

Comment: Hint: calling your integral $f(x)$, use differentiation under the integral sign to set up an ODE.

Comment: Expand the exponent and get the Fourier transform of a Gaussian integral.

Comment: @Volodymyr Did any of us answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

With the change of integration variables $t=ap - {\rm i}bx$,
$$
\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - (ap - {\rm i}bx)^2 } {\rm d}p}  = \frac{1}{a}\int_{ - \infty  - {\rm i}bx}^{ + \infty  - {\rm i}bx} {{\rm e}^{ - t^2 } {\rm d}t} .
$$
Now since $b$ and $x$ are real, we can use Cauchy's theorem to deform the contour of integration back to the real line and obtain
$$
\frac{1}{a}\int_{ - \infty  - {\rm i}bx}^{ + \infty  - {\rm i}bx} {{\rm e}^{ - t^2 } {\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{a}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - t^2 } {\rm d}t}  = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{a}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this problem.

As you properly did, consider first the problem of the antiderivative
$$I=\int e^{-(ap - ibx)^2}\, dp=\frac{1}{a}\int e^{-m^2} \,dm=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 a}\text{erf}(m)$$
Go back to $p$
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 a}\text{erf}(ap-ibx)$$ Now, use the bounds